# How to use `IterableStorageMap`

Tags: storage, frame

So currently, I need to iterate over the StorageMap defined like this:

```
pub(super) type Report<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, (T::AccountId, HealthRound), Reports<T::AccountId,HealthRound>, OptionQuery>;
```

And to solve this, I found `IterableStorageMap` in `frame_support::storage`, So I defined it like this

```
pub(super) type Report<T: Config> = IterableStorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, (T::AccountId, HealthRound), Reports<T::AccountId,HealthRound>, OptionQuery>;
```

Upon doing this, I get an error like this

```
error: Invalid pallet::storage, expected ident: `StorageValue` or `StorageMap` or `StorageDoubleMap` or `StorageNMap` in order to expand metadata, found `IterableStorageMap`.
```

Am I missing something? It would be of great help if someone who has already used this can explain how to initialize this type of `StorageItem`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might not need to use an explicit `IterableStorageMap` as a normal `StorageMap` supports iterating both over the keys as well as they values, see the [Documentation](https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/frame_support/storage/types/struct.StorageMap.html#method.iter):

1. Either via the `KeyPrefixIterator` by calling `Report::<T>::iter_keys()`
2. Or via the `PrefixIterator` by calling `Report::<T>::iter_values()`

for

```rust
pub(super) type Report<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, (T::AccountId, HealthRound), Reports<T::AccountId,HealthRound>, OptionQuery>;
```

Comment: To add to this, `IterableStorageMap` is a trait, not a type. The concrete `StorageMap` exposed by `frame_support` is an `IterableStorageMap`, so this is why it has `iter_keys` and `iter_values` methods.

Comment: So you don't need to update the type of the storage map, but just ensure that the `IterableStorageMap` trait is in scope so you can use its methods by importing `IterableStorageMap`.